# Creating a view with relation between taxonomy term fields of two different content types

Tags: views, entities

I have two content types - Page and Article, both having a field called "tag"(entity reference to taxonomy term) and both using the same vocabulary. I want to create a block "Linked Articles" and display it in "Pages". The block should contain a titles of all "linked" articles. With "linked" I mean articles which have the same tag(s) that current page has.

For example, I got pages:

- Sport(tag="sport")
- Music(tag="music")
- Food(tag="food")

and articles:

- Article about Rap Music(tag="music")
- Article about Jazz(tag="music")
- Article about Football(tag="sport")
- Article about making a Pizza(tag="food")

The result:
When I open "Music" page, there is a block "Linked articles" containing "Article about Rap Music" and "Article about Jazz" and so on...